# How should one make a class with dependencies unit testable without bloat?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, tdd

So I have a class (part of a library) that facilitates two-way TCP communication. Part of that is accepting incoming connections.

My implementation consists of using a TCPListener object and a multithreaded method to accept connections. To make it testable, I decided to instead create an "INetworkListener" interface, which contains only a single event, "OnClientAccepted". This way, I can use dependency injection to mock a fake version of TCPListener and avoid multithreaded unit tests.

The problem is that I need a way to test the class using a fake INetworkListener, but I want my users to **not** have the option to use other implementations of this interface.

Here is some stripped down sample code:

```
class TcpMessenger
{
    // Various properties

    private INetworkListener _tcpListener;

    public TcpMessenger(int port, string friendlyName) // This is the ONLY constructor I want available to users
    {
        ServerPort = port;
        FriendlyName = friendlyName;
        _isRunning = false;
        _tcpListener = new ConcreteExample(port); // This prevents unit testing because it opens threads and such
    }

    public TcpMessenger(int port, string friendlyName, INetworkListener listener) // I need this to test
    {
        ServerPort = port;
        FriendlyName = friendlyName;
        _isRunning = false;
        _tcpListener = listener; // No dependency here :)
    }
}
```

**Why can't I just leave both constructors?**

My library acts as sort of a facade. It makes TCP communication easier, but doesn't add much functionality. Therefore, my target audience would never need to inject that dependency. And if I don't want them to do it, then proper design tells me to enforce it.

**Why not just test it as a public-facing API? Integration Testing!**

I actually did this with a previous version of my library, which was extremely coupled. The results were terrible. I had a dozen tests that involved multiple threads, and worse, actual sockets. Unit tests shouldn't be dependent on outside factors like that.

**Do you really need to test this?**

Yes. This library has high-level functionality, such as exception handling, error reporting, failsafes for connection issues, and algorithms to maintain two-way connections (meaning each node is a client and server). This functionality can be tested without opening actual sockets, so I definitely want that.

I also want the unit tests to be public. Meaning anyone can grab the source, run them, and see all the green check marks.

**Concluding Question:**

How do I test two classes independently, while simultaneously forcing dependencies in real-world scenarios?

Comment: `want my users to not have the option to use other implementations of this interface.` Why? If they do another implementation, so be it. But if you still want to, you can use the attribute `InternalsVisibleTo` on your interface so it is only visible to your assembly.

Comment: It just doesn't blend well with the design goals I've set out. Honestly, this is extremely low stakes. It's more of a proof-of-concept. Even if I choose to leave it as is, there could be another situation in which it's more serious.

Comment: If the consumer of your API is intentionally writing code and implementing your interface to do other things which do not play well with the rest of your code, then that is their issue. Honestly, I would not worry about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your constructor internal and expose your internals to your tests using `InternalsVisibleTo`:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourNamespace.YourTests")]
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx